# Oracle Coalesce two rows in one

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, dense-rank

I plan to coalesce two (many) rows into one line. My data looks like this

```
╔══════════╦════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ ReportID ║  Item  ║ StartDt   ║ EndDt     ║ Statement  ║
╠══════════╬════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  1       ║ 3000   ║ 11-Mar-16 ║ (null)    ║ Remark     ║
╠══════════╬════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  1       ║ 3001   ║ 11-Mar-16 ║ 13-Mar-16 ║ (null)     ║
╠══════════╬════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  2       ║ 4002   ║ 24-May-16 ║ 27-May-16 ║ Remark1    ║
╠══════════╬════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  2       ║ 4003   ║ 24-May-16 ║ 28-May-16 ║ Remark1    ║
╚══════════╩════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

I would love to merge by `ReportID` and use different rules:

- Use highest `endDt`
- Use `Statement` that is not `null`
- Use `Statement` of the record with the highest `Item`

Hence, the result should be

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ ReportID ║ StartDt   ║ EndDt     ║ Statement  ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  1       ║ 11-Mar-16 ║ 13-Mar-16 ║ Remark     ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  2       ║ 24-May-16 ║ 28-May-16 ║ Remark1    ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

I need to achieve this with plain SQL and cannot write PL-SQL routines.

#### Data

```
SELECT 1 as ReportID, 3000 as Item, TO_DATE('11-03-2016') as StartDt, TO_DATE(NULL) as EndDt, 'Remark' as Statement FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 1, 3001, TO_DATE('11-03-2016'), TO_DATE('13-03-2016'), NULL FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2, 4002, TO_DATE('24-05-2016'), TO_DATE('27-05-2016'), 'Remark1' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2, 4003, TO_DATE('24-05-2016'), TO_DATE('28-05-2016'), 'Remark1' FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want one row per `reportid`, so you'd group by it. Then use the appropriate aggregation functions (which is `KEEP FIRST/LAST` for the statement column) to get the desired values:

```
select 
  reportid,
  max(startdt) as startdt,
  max(enddt) as enddt,
  max(statement) keep (dense_rank last 
                         order by case when statement is null then 1 else 2 end, item
                      ) as statement
from mytable
group by reportid
order by reportid;
```

Comment: The hint with `keep` and `last` was very valuable! Thx a lot!